# Having trouble with indexing in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset with the following details:

- 1.4 million nodes
- 2.9 million relationships
- 15 million properties (including gender, name, subscriber_id etc)
- 1 relationship type (Contacted)

I've batch imported the data into the database on my machine (64 bit, 16 core, 16 GB RAM) using https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20

I'm trying to index these nodes on Subscriber_ID, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

I ran

```
start n = node(*) set n:Subscribers
```

My understanding is this creates a label for each of the nodes (is this correct)

Next I ran

```
create index on :Subscribers(SUBSCRIBER_ID)
```

Which I think should create an index for all nodes with the 'Subscribers' label on the property 'SUBSCRIBER_ID'. (correct?)

Now when I go to Neo4j-sh and run

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ schema
==> Indexes
==>   ON :Subscribers(SU_SUBSCRIBER_ID) ONLINE  
==> 
==> No constraints
```

But when I run the following it says there are no indices set for the nodes.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ index --indexes
==> Node indexes:
==> 
==> Relationship indexes:
```

I have a few questions

1. Do I have to tell it to index the existing data? If so how do I do
   that?
2. How can I then use the index? I've read through the
   documentation but I had a bit of trouble following it.
3. It looks
   like I can have the indexes set up when I run the batch import
   script, but I can't really understand how... could someone explain
   please?

Here's an example of my data:

**Nodes.txt**

```
id  SU_SUBSCRIBER_ID    CU_FIRST_NAME   gender  SU_AGE
0   123456                       Ann    F        56
1   832746                         ?    UNKNOWN  -1
2   546765                       Tom    UNKNOWN  -1
3   768345                     Anges    F        72
4   267854                  Aoibhlinn   F        38
```

**rels.csv**

```
start   end rel counter 
0            3  CONTACTED   2
1            2  CONTACTED   1
1            4  CONTACTED   1
3            2  CONTACTED   2
4            1  CONTACTED   1
```

Answer (score 1):

`schema` is the right command to look at.

Cypher uses the label indexes automatically for `MERGE` and `MATCH`.

With the Java Core-API you'd use `db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label,property,value)`

You did the right thing, except for one. You could have created the labels on the nodes while doing the batch-import.

Just add a `l:label` field to your CSV-file containing a comma separated list of labels per node. Like shown in the readme on that branch.